# jstree types plugin

Tags: json, plugins, types, jstree

This is my current JSON input for my jstree (using jstree-grid for the data):

```
{
   data: "StrukturNavn",
   attr: {id:"1", class:"structureNode", contentItemId:"123", rel:"root"},
   children: [
              {
                data: "Seksjon 1",
                attr: {id:"2", class:"structureNode", contentItemId:"231"}
              }
             ]
}
```

And this is the relevant jstree code:

```
types: {
         root : {delete_node: false}
       },
plugins: ["json_data", "crrm", "ui", "themes", "grid", "types"],
```

But, for some reason, the root node is still deletable, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, I was simply not configuring the plugin correctly.

```
types: {
         root : {delete_node: false}
       },
```

should be

```
types: {
         valid_children: ["root"],
         types: {
                   root : {delete_node: false}
                }
        },
```